# SMART test hard disk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, smart

I'm trying to understand if my disk has some problems or not.
I have a Western Digital `wdc wd10eads-00m2b0` that sometimes crashes. Fortunally is not my primary drive, is just for storage but happen that Windows dismount it and I need to reboot to make it work, maybe moving a little bit the SATA cable. I was thinking that these crashes are due to the cable because have some turns and it's quite rigid, but then I tried with some tests.

First I checked with Defraggler, in the INFO window and there are no warnings there.

Then I tried with the trial version of HD Tune Pro Drive and it gave me two warnings
[image: screenshot]
so I launched a Scan Disk from the property first and from CMD later, but both don't find any problems.

To confirm it I used the WD tool Lifeguard Diagnostic, but here there are no warnings
[image: screenshot]

At this point I'm trying with EaseUS Partition Master. It is completing the superficial test, but it's at 95% and it didn't find anything.

What is it your response for my HDD? Is it working or not? 3 out of 4 tests are passed, just HD Tune Drive gives me warnings.

**EDIT**

Using GSmartControl i found [image: this] and errors [image: screenshot]

Comment: Check also SMART attributes with GSmartControl, it looks like HD tune found parameter C5(197) greater than zero. If GSmartControl confirm it then replace this HDD ASAP.

Comment: Yes confirm it. I edited the question adding these results

Comment: Then replace it ASAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR
Its time to replace the drive. its not trustworthy anymore.

Long answer:
your disk has bad blocks/sectors that have not been reallocated yet (current pending sectors), and your disk crashes are likely related to the failures that accompany reading one of them. Running `chkdsk \R` will attempt to remap (reallocate) them to another location, which may solve that immediate problem (or it may run your disk to death). This will show in your smart stats by the Current Pending Sectors returning to 0 and the Reallocated sector count increasing to 18.

Bad sectors tend to grow at an exponential rate. once you have more than a couple of them, its time to backup your data and replace the disk.

I do not recommend you use utilities like defragmentation tools on a drive in this state. They cause lots of moves between sectors, and you may need all the remaining life the disk has to copy your data off it. just the process of copying the files to another disk will automatically defragment them.

Comment: It is possible to know which could be the cause? I've got two identical HDD, one is this one and the other one has the OS installed. The second one works correctly. Can be due to the energy save setting that switch off the HDD when inactive?

Comment: It could be literally anything from manufacturing tolerances, knocks during shipping, vibration, different amount of use or positioning in the case or orientation.   It could indeed be due to energy saving causing the drive to spin up and down more frequently and relatedly having to handle temperature gradients more often.

Comment: Can be solved filling the HDD with zeros? I'm not saying a full format, but write zeros in the entire HDD. I think CCleaner gives this possibility. Before replace it I want cover all the possibilities

Comment: @Shika93 Internal firmware of HHD is really unhappy to remap broken sectors and waiting till some threshold will be reached, sometime you need to write to the same broken sectors hundred times till sector would be remapped.  It better to use for such tasks MHDD of Victoria or something else like that tools

Comment: HDD Low Level Format tool works as well?

Comment: I know you are looking for a software solution to this problem, but I really can't recommend you use this disk for anything you would miss if the disk fails tomorrow.